# Calling a Class to display a Table inside RelativeLayout child

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a problem.

I have a complex class who create a big table:

```
Table(Context context,String[][] matrix)
```

I call that class from the `ActivityMain` using the instructions:

```
 Table table = new Table(this,Matrix);
 setContentView(table);
```

And work perfect expanding the table to all the screen.

Here is the problem. Now I want some space for the toolbar menu, so I modify the `XML` to create it on this way:

```
RelativeLayout

          Toolbar Menu (child)

          RelativeLayout (child)

RelativeLayout
```

But when I call the class to create the table, still expand it a long all the screen and I can not see the menu. My idea is create the Table inside the second `RelativeLayout` who is below Toolbar Menu.

But I don't know what to put here to make it:

```
Table table = new Table(_____HERE______,Matrix);

 setContentView(table);
```

I don't want to modify the class `Table`, so there is a way to do it in `ActivityMain` to display the table inside second `RelativeLayout` to let me see the `ToolbarMenu`?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding `Table` to layout, but replacing it.

Easiest way to resolve it is to create a container `layout` for example `FrameLayout` in your activity layout and add `Table` inside of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/container"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your activity do:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
container.addView(new Table(this,Matrix));
```